# Symfony 5 debug tool bar not showing on error page

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I work a lot with symfony, but this time, when i start a new project with the "symfony new my_project --full" command, i have a problem with the debug toolbar.

I only add User entity with php bin/console make:user, i add authentication with php bin/console make:auth

When i go on controller route like the login page, i can see the debug toolbar, but if i do a 404 error with the route "/qwerty", the debug toolbar isn't showing and i have a javascript error in the console who said : "**Uncaught TypeError: Sfjs.loadToolbar is not a function**".
I have this error on every error page like 403, 500.

I try to remove and reinstall the profiler, i update composer, clear the cache, but nothing change.

I follow the instructions on this answer : [My profiler toolbar isn't showing up in symfony 4.3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593887/my-profiler-toolbar-isnt-showing-up-in-symfony-4-3-1#answer-58853809)
but everything seems to be ok except the 'Note' at the end of this one : [only difference with answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9uss.png)

I try to make a new project with another PC (i thought i had a problem with my configuration), but it's the same thing.

I have a `<body>` and a `</body>` in my base.html.twig, the others template are extending to this one, so it's not a  missing's problem.

This is all i found about this problem on my research, can you help me with this one please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue and it's tracked here https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/41305
and fixed in 4.4 (will be merged in 5.3, and possibly 5.2) related PR https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/41346

In time of writing (2021-05-22) fix is not released to public packages.

Comment: Thank you, i hope they will fix this quickly then !