# Symfony 6 debug toolbar not showing

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm using Symfony 6.3 but not seeing the debug toolbar.

I have the web-profiler and debug-bundle installed. My env file is set to APP_ENV=dev. My web_profiler.yaml is set to toolbar=true.

What else might I need to check here?

Comment: Did you check whether the markup for the profiler is added? Whether the toolbar loads the profiler data? Whether any errors are written to your browser's developer console? How do you generate the response after all?

Comment: @NicoHaase Thank you! It seems that DOCTYPE and other basic HTML structure was required for the toolbar to appear. Probably needs those containers to add itself. I was playing with a template with just some raw text. If you add an answer I'm happy to give you the tick mark.

Comment: The toolbar is appended just before the closing of the `<body>` tag. Therefore, it will only show if your HTML document contains a `<body>`

Comment: @Altherius please put your comment in an answer

Comment: There is a good list of things to check (including the </body> tag) on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58853809/11350193

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The toolbar is appended just before the closing of the `<body>` tag. Therefore, it will only show if your HTML document contains a `<body>`